# Change default color of Bootstrap btn-primary class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I know I can simply do this in my SCSS file.  But I would like to know the correct way to do it via customizing the actual Bootstrap colors.  I have already figured out how to change background colors on the buttons.

I created a `custom-bootstrap.scss` file in which I modified the `$primary` and `$danger` variables and then imported Bootstrap.
`custom-bootstrap.scss:`

```
// Override default variables before the import
$primary: #48BF91;
$danger: #CF6676;

// Import Bootstrap and its default variables
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

This is my inspector showing where it sets the text color to black from the `_buttons.scss` file.
[image]

**Edit:** So right now, this is how I am currently changing the button text color.  Just by adding this code into my own SCSS file.  But it feels too hacky for me, I want to modify the Bootstrap variables.

```
.btn-primary {
    color: $text;

    &:hover {
        color: $text;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is the correct way ... the classes of helpers and elements are computed based on map `$theme-colors:('primary': $primary, ...)` but the simple changing of the system color works on the base direct for var `$primary` ... and automatic changes in `$theme-colors` and all styles as well.

Comment: I don't fully understand your comment.  I understand that is the correct way to change the background color of the button.  I want to know how to change the text color.

Answer (score 0):

use this type

```
:root {--button-color: black; --button-background-color: silver;}
```